# Incrementar Id con un INSERT en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Tengo una tabla con diferentes campos, quiero hacer un `INSERT` en el que las nuevas sentencias tengan el `Id` a partir del último.

¿Cómo podria hacerlo?

He pensado en hacer algo así:

```
insert into id = id + 1
```

Pero no estoy convencido de que funcione, podrían ayudarme.

Comment: Hola CMorillo. Debes mostar lo que has intentado junto a la explicacion de lo que te sucede: error de consulta, resultado no deseado, ... Si no, es demasiado amplia la pregunta. Muestranos un ejemplo de los datos que tienes y como quedaria tras el insert. Para más informacion tienes [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Todavía no he probado nada por no cargarme la base de datos. Lo que pretendo es si el ultimo id es 20 crear un insert que comience a añadir sentencias con un id mayor que 20 y que se vaya incrementando en cada sentencia

Comment: Pues lo más importante es probar. Para no cargarte nada, copia la tabla para hacer una tabla de pruebas y ahi lo intentas.

Comment: La próxima vez si pones tu estructura de tablas será mejor D:

Comment: Las respuestas que te pusieron aplican para MySQL y las etiquetas que pones son para SQL Server. Me pregunto cómo es que la aceptaste cuando ni siquiera aplican para la tecnología de la cual tienes el problema. De igual forma a los que votaron +1. Esto sale de la política de preguntas puntuales a problemas puntuales de programación.

Comment: @lois6b tuve que poner una respuesta, no quería más información que no tiene nada qué ver con la tecnología que el OP pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para poder insertar un `Id` auto incrementable, la mejor práctica es definirlo en la tabla con la propiedad `IDENTITY`:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabla (
    Id           INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Descripcion  VARCHAR (64) NULL
    -- Aquí va la definición de los demás campos
);
```

Par realizar el `INSERT`, simplemente omites el campo Id, ya que internamente se realiza la parte autoincrementable:

```
INSERT INTO Tabla (Descripcion) VALUES ('Alguna descripción con Id 1')
INSERT INTO Tabla (Descripcion) VALUES ('Alguna descripción con Id 2')
```

El resultado será el siguiente:

```
+----+-----------------------------+
| Id | Descripcion                 |
+----+-----------------------------+
| 1  | Alguna descripción con Id 1 |
+----+-----------------------------+
| 2  | Alguna descripción con Id 2 |
+----+-----------------------------+
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración y sus resultados](http://rextester.com/EVF30889)</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Esto podría servirte de ejemplo, pero como te dicen en los comentarios lo más importante es probar y probar (Así se aprende más)

```
   INSERT [INTO] nombreTabla (id, atributo, atributo2)
     VALUES ((SELECT TOP 1 id FROM nombreTabla ORDER BY id DESC)+1, "atributo1", "atributo2");
```

También en las creación de la tabla existe el **AUTO-INCREMENT** un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Personas (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    nombre varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    apellidos varchar(30),
    nif varchar(24),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Y a la hora de insertar en la tabla no es necesario decirle el **ID**:

```
INSERT Personas (lastName,firstName,nif) VALUES ("Juan", "Gonzalez", "00000000X");
```

Comment: @Flxtr, Tienes toda la razón, ahora lo cambio. Gracias por darte cuenta

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que ir a la pestaña de estructura y a tu columna `id` ponerle el atributo autoincrement.

Así cuando hagas un `INSERT INTO  mitabla (nombre) VALUES ('pepe')` te autoincrementará el id de esa línea.

No es correcto setear a mano el id porque mysql tiene datos ocultos y cosas suyas para optimizar las consultas :S

Un ejemplo para marcar un id autoincremental:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Bueno, ambos sacamos el mismo ejemplo ^^

Comment: Uy, al editar no me di cuenta perdona, si te la dan como buena elimino la respuesta

Comment: Sin problemas, publicaste tu primero ;)

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` es para MySQL, y lo que el OP requiere es para SQL Server. En este caso lo que requiere es un `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

*Si buscas una respuestas para* **SQL Server**, encontré una fácil y es seleccionar el valor máximo de dicha columna (Que en este caso seria el que tu necesitas = id) y guardarlo en una variable, esto principalmente lo estoy haciendo en un procedimiento almacenado, luego de esto debes pasarle el argumento en VALUES, le pasas dicha variable y le agregas + 1. Mira un ejemplo

```
create procedure dbo.nuevoUsuario(
    @id INT,  -- Esta y la de abajo son declaraciones de variables en SQL
    @nombre VARCHAR(50)
)

SELECT @id = MAX(ID) FROM usuarios; -- Definimos el valor del id, que en este caso será el máximo registro que tenga dicha tabla.

INSERT INTO usuarios( 
    id
    nombre
)
VALUES(@id + 1, @nombre);
```

Y por ultimo, cuando llames el procedimiento, en el primer argumento que le vas a pasar, que en este caso será el id, pásalo como null, y ya este te creara un nuevo id + 1, sin perder su orden.

```
dbo.nuevoUsuario null, 'Andrés Romaña'
GO
```

Espero le sirva a alguien, gracias Jesús.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un `IDENTITY (1,1)` e ira iterando el valor cuando hagas el *insert* de la siguiente manera:

```
 CREATE TABLE Personas (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    nombre varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    apellidos varchar(30),
    documento varchar(24),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes también poner tu ID de tipo serial así:

```
 CREATE TABLE Personas (
    ID serial,
    nombre varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    apellidos varchar(30),
    documento varchar(24),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Con esto solo sería la declaración de la tabla, ¿de qué forma se auto incrementaría el Id?

Answer (score -2):

Resultó ser más fácil de lo que pensé.

Tengo pgAdmin 4 y quise restaurar un backup de pgAdmin3 (v. 9.3). Cree la nueva base de datos y, cuando quería restaurar el backup, me salía un error.

Lo solucioné borrando el esquema público en la nueva base de datos creada:

```
drop SCHEMA public;
```

Y luego restauré con total normalidad. FUNCIONA!! :D

Comment: Esta respuesta no está relacionada con la pregunta